# Best practice for using global scoped variables?

Tags: python

Consider the following code:

```python
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self._stuff = []

    def addStuff(self, what):
        self._stuff.append(what)
        stuff.append(what)

def addStuff(what):
    stuff.append(what)

stuff = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
addStuff('stuff1')
Test().addStuff('stuff2')
print stuff # ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'stuff1', 'stuff2']
```

This works perfectly fine and has the intended result. But, coming from Java, I feel compelled to do this:

```python
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self._stuff = []

    def addStuff(self, stuff, what):
        self._stuff.append(what)
        stuff.append(what)

def addStuff(stuff, what):
    stuff.append(what)

stuff = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
addStuff(stuff, 'stuff1')
Test().addStuff(stuff, 'stuff2')
print stuff # ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'stuff1', 'stuff2']
```

The result is the same. Is there any real differences/benefits between the two? Which one is considered better practice/more Pythonic?

Comment: It is always best practice to pass arguments and return values. Relying on global mutable state is bad

Comment: And this is true for most languages, it's not a Python-specific practice.

Comment: The example is too artificial to determine a "right" option. None of this code makes any sense either way. With just a class named `Test` and a list named `stuff`, we can't tell how `Test` should know about `stuff`. All we can do is give the default advice of "mutable global state is usually bad".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second way is better. Using arguments is much more flexible because it allows different values to be used each time you call the function. If you ever wished to use another value in place of `stuff` within `addStuff`, you would have to make an entirely new function. Additionally, it's usually bad practice to use global variables because it can cause hard-to-find bugs and unnecessary complications.

See also: [Why are global variables evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)